# how to position two transparent images to overlap opposite corners of a container div

Tags: css, image, positioning, html, overlapping

I got this PSD comp from a print graphic designer and I'm not sure it's doable on the web.
Please note that the blacked bordered, rounded-corner container (pictured below), already exists.  There are several z-indexed divs on this page, so it's hard to figure out which one has the priority in stacking order.

[image]

As you can see, I have the two grey ribbons on top (representing a box with ribbon and an ornament) stationed on the top-left and bottom-right corners, along with two images (the smaller blue boxes i.e.: To:/From:) underneath those "ribbons" but on top of the container.  The background color for the container is white.  The top-left corner has to have a transparent background so that the smaller blue box will show through. Can someone tell me how position these "slanted ribbon" on this rounded corner container div?  Or if this can even be done using CSS and HTML.

Comment: Are you using the `z-index` CSS property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest answer is to have two `<img>`'s, and have them both absolutely positioned.  Position one with a `top:0px; left:0px`; and one with a `bottom:0px; and right:0px`;.  Give them a high z-index to ensure they are at the top of the div.  Make sure the parent div has `position: relative` defined.

Comment: Make sure you update your post with what worked and mark the question as resolved once you do, future Googlers will love you for it :).

Comment: I will definitely mark the answer that worked. I'm just reading thru the article now and then I'll try both answers here.  I'll probably have to do some z-indexing, as I have those two other images (small blue boxes) that need to go behind the ribbons, plus text as well, right?  Thanks

Comment: Whetstone (or anyone), for IE7-8, what is the markup for positioning two images on one div?  `#h_main {
 width:960px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 border:10px solid #027cb4;
 position:relative;
 border-radius: 10px;
 zoom:1;
 text-align:left;

}`Sidebar:  for some reason the "@" format is not working to notify.

Comment: I'm unsure what the problem is.  I've got it working on Firefox, Chrome, and IE7 (under wine in linux, no windows test environment).  See here: http://jsfiddle.net/yKBmY/2/